# Typescript types for Tailwind CSS classes

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css

Do typescript types for Tailwind CSS classes exist anywhere?

I'm trying to pass some tailwind classes as a prop to a React component, and want to type it properly.

Comment: [This npm types package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/tailwindcss) might help, and also [this github project](https://github.com/thien-do/typed.tw)

Comment: Use this: https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-1#first-party-type-script-types

Comment: @Axedyson would be nice with a more comprehensive answer to the question :)

Comment: @leto did you solve this? Are you able to type-hint different Tailwind options on properties? let's say you have an object `{padding: 'p2'}`, which type do you type-hint this? and do you get any autocomplete? I've tried using the CSSRuleObject type, but it's just taking any string... not validating if it's a part of any of the Tailwind css options?

I can't find any types related to this... there is the ThemeConfig, but is this one related to your own custom theme or not? I don't seem to be able to figure out how to get correct tailwind classes as autocomplete.

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 Apologies but I haven't used tailwind alone for a while so can't remember. I started using twin.macro, which is tailwind-in-js, which resolves this issue.

Answer (score 13):

I also couldn't find a type definition anywhere, so I did this as a work around.
My goal was to be able to get the intellisense from tailwind, and this worked for me...

```
/* This returns the interface object of all props/attributes on a jsx div element */
React.ComponentProps<'div'>

/* Then this would get the types on the className attribute */
React.ComponentProps<'div'>['className']
```

Example application...

```
interface Props {
  className?: React.ComponentProps<'div'>['className'];
}
```

Comment: Wonderful find, is there a generic way to define this ! can 'div' be changed where it accepts most of the html elements ?

Comment: This unfortunately works only if the prop name is "className". Couldn't make it work with custom prop names.

Comment: @shankaranarayanan try React.HTMLProps<HTMLElement>["className"]

Answer (score 8):

There is a **package that provides the classname type of tailwindcss.** [**Check it out**](https://github.com/danpacho/tailwindest).

```
type TailwindColor = Tailwindest["color"]

// becomes
//`text-[${string}]` | "text-slate-100" | "text-slate-200" | "text-slate-300" | "text-slate-500" | "text-slate-700" | "text-slate-50" | "text-slate-400" | "text-slate-600" | "text-slate-800"  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

if you can get by with purely intellisense (i.e. no actual type safety), then you can simply add your prop as an attribute to the tailwind intellisense extension

[image: tailwind intellisense extension settings]

[image: tailwind intellisense on custom prop]

Answer (score 3):

I used the html classname type and it works fine :

```
import { FC, HTMLProps, ReactNode } from "react";

interface TextProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: HTMLProps<HTMLElement>["className"];
}

const Text: FC<TextProps> = ({ children, className }) => {
  return <div className={`capitalize ${className}`}>{children}</div>;
};

export default Text;
```